# Is this React app far too simple to use Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux

While using ReactJS, I have a parent component, which contains two children components:

```
- Main
    - NewReminder
    - ExistingReminders
```

Main passes information to `NewReminder` as well as `ExistingReminders` through props. When a `NewReminder` is created, it must update the list that the user sees of `ExistingReminders`. This seems like a great use of redux, where the state can be updated from `NewReminder`, and will update this list, but I don't know if there are alternatives as this might be far too simple to set up an entire redux environment?

Should I go ahead and begin implementing Redux, or do you have any suggestions for alternatives?

Comment: you can also check mobx. It has less boilerplate and uses OOP and reactive programming practices. https://mobx.js.org/getting-started.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's really quite a broad question, but I'll give it a crack: you should consider taking [the advice of the author](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/you-might-not-need-redux-be46360cf367):

> Seriously, it bears repeating.
>
> *Local state is fine.*
>
> The tradeoff that Redux offers is to *add indirection* to decouple “what happened” from “how things change”.
>
> Is it always a good thing to do? No. It’s a tradeoff.

Redux doesn't have to be complicated (in fact, you could argue it goes out of its way to stay fairly light and simple). Once you've set up the basics a few times it's not intimidating. However, if you *can* write a simple application without Redux in a way that's clear and maintainable, sounds like a win to me!